# Indeed parsing xml jobs Slow

Tags: php, xml

im developing a website that outputs data from indeed jobs, the script is working but i notice that is very slow for the data to show comparing with other websites that makes the same functionality, so i wonder if i could optimize my code to accomplish a better result. Above i leave the code:

```
<?php

function curl_request(){

// Get cURL resource

$curl = curl_init();

// Set some options
$country = "pt";
$jobType = "PHP;
$city = "Belem";
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

// Return the response as a string instead of outputting it to the screen

CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
//URL to send request to
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&q='.$jobType.'&l='.$city.'&sort=&radius=&st=&jt=&start=&limit=&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co='.$country.'&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2',

));

// Send the request & save response to $resp

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

// Close request to clear up some resources

curl_close($curl);

return $resp;

}



function xmlToArray($input, $callback = null, $recurse = false) {

$data = ((!$recurse) && is_string($input))? simplexml_load_string($input, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA): $input;

if ($data instanceof SimpleXMLElement) $data = (array) $data;

if (is_array($data)) foreach ($data as &$item) $item = xmlToArray($item, $callback, true);

return (!is_array($data) && is_callable($callback))? call_user_func($callback, $data): $data;

}

?>

<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
<body>

<ol>

<?php

for($i=0;$i<25;$i++){    // using for loop to show number of  jobs

$resp=curl_request($i);

$arrXml = xmlToArray($resp);

$results=$arrXml['results'];

?>

<li>

<p>

<strong>Job :<a href="<?php echo $results['result'][$i]['url']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $results['result'][$i]['jobtitle']; ?></a></strong>

</p>

<p><strong>Location: <?php echo $results['result'][$i]['city']; ?></strong></p>

<p><strong>Date :<?php echo $results['result'][$i]['date'];?></strong></p>

<p> Descriptions :<?php echo $results['result'][$i]['snippet']; ?></p>

</li>

<?php } ?>

</ol>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of using simpleXML that is slow, rewrite your code to use XMLReader that is faster (but more difficult to use).

Comment: hard? not really, i leave a example here:

[http://pastebin.com/XPaidsBT]